# How can I monitor a bash script?

Tags: bash

I am running a bash script that takes hours. I was wondering if there is way to monitor what is it doing? like what part of the script is currently running, how long did it take to run the whole script, if it crashes at what line of the script stopped working, etc. I just want to receive feedback from the script. Thanks!!!

Comment: You can add `-x` in the first line, like this: `#!/bin/bash -ex`. The `-e` is to exit immediately when a command exits with error.

Comment: also -v can be used instead of -x to get a less cluttered output

Comment: Does your script contain `echo` or `printf` statements? If not, the above comments should help you. If it does, and you can't see them because the script runs in the background, then the solution is different. Please make it clear which case it is in your question.

Comment: Also, `pstree` can show which process(es) your script is currently waiting on, if any, if you know the pid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

from man page for bash,

```
set -x 
After expanding each simple command, for command, case command, select command, or arithmetic for command, display the expanded value of PS4, followed by the command and its expanded arguments or associated word list.
```

add these to the start of your script,

```
export PS4='+{${BASH_SOURCE}:$LINENO} '
set -x
```

Example,

```
#!/bin/bash          

export PS4='+{${BASH_SOURCE}:$LINENO} '
set -x

echo Hello World
```

Result,

```
+{helloworld.sh:6} echo Hello World
Hello World
```

Answer (score 1):

Make a status or log file. For example add this inside your script:

```
echo $(date) - Ok >> script.log
```

Or for a real monitoring you can use `strace` on linux for see system call, example:

```
$ while true ; do sleep 5 ; done &
[1] 27190
$ strace -p 27190
```